# TestNG options not display in Run As in eclips even I added Test NG Jar

Tags: selenium, testng

I have added testng-7.4.0.jar in my project as external jar but I am not getting TestNG as options to run the program under run as in eclipse . I can see TestNg jar present in Referenced Libraries
I tried this in both version of eclipse oxygen and Neon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGjq2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Install Testng plugin from eclipse market place and restart the IDE. And when you run it for the first time configure the run with run configurations.

Answer (score -1):

You must have TestNG.xml file configured to run in eclipse.

Comment: @ itronic . I am new to test automation ... how to configured TestNG.xml

Comment: Right click on the project --> TestNG --> Convert to TestNG --> Finish